# How to set more conditions (targets) in the Time Series Node in SPSS Modeler?

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

could you please advise if it is possible to calculate the predictions in `SPSS Modeler` when having two conditions for the model

i.e. we need to calculate the future values for the respective `ID` and at the same time we need to see the split per `Var1`.

So far we have used Time Series node but there we set just one target Value (`currency1`). Would it be please possible to have the output in the format that we have one figure as the prediction for the respective ID and having there also `Var1` reflected in the split. We need this split per `Var1` as one ID has more values in `Var1`, so it is not the case as in `Var3` where we have just one value assigned to the `ID`.

```
ID | Value (currency1) | Value (currency2) | Period   | Var1 | Var2 | Var3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
U1 | 1000              | 1200              | 1/1/2000 | 100  | abc  | 1p1
U1 | 500               | 600               | 2/1/2000 | 100  | abc  | 1p1
U1 | 700               | 840               | 3/1/2000 | 200  | def  | 1p1
U2 | 500               | 600               | 1/1/2000 | 100  | ghj  | 1p2
U2 | 800               | 960               | 4/1/2000 | 300  | abc  | 1p2
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help / advice.